# Transform rectangle with transformation matrix Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transpose

I´ve given the following rectangle and I want to transform it (given ax and M) corresponding to a transformation matrix M. The problem I have it that the matrix "lines" and "M" have different dimensions.

```
lines = np.array([[-1, 1, 1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1]])
    
basis = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]) 
    
# Transform lines and basis using M    
ax = M.dot(lines.T) # This is my attempt to transform the axis
    
    
ax.plot( lines[0,:], lines[1,:], '-', color="gray" )
ax.arrow( 0, 0, basis[0][0], basis[1][0], color='red', width=.04, length_includes_head=True )
ax.arrow( 0, 0, basis[0][1], basis[1][1], color='gold', width=.04, length_includes_head=True )

ax.set_xlim( -5, 5 )
ax.set_ylim( -5, 5 )
ax.grid()
```

I hope I´ve pointed my problem out clearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your almost done the solution. Here is your code with some fixes to make in work.

```
from math import sin, cos
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def get_rotation_2d(theta):
    """ Return 2D rotation matrix
    """
    R = np.array([
        [cos(theta), -sin(theta)],
        [sin(theta),  cos(theta)]
    ])
    return R


# initial rectangle and basis
lines = np.array([[-1, 1, 1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1]])
basis = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])

# transformation
M = get_rotation_2d(np.pi / 6)
new_lines = M @ lines
new_basis = M @ basis

# plot results
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(new_lines[0, :], new_lines[1, :], '-', color='gray')
ax.arrow( 0, 0, new_basis[0][0], new_basis[1][0], color='red', width=.04, length_includes_head=True )
ax.arrow( 0, 0, new_basis[0][1], new_basis[1][1], color='gold', width=.04, length_includes_head=True )
ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

I use Python 3.5+ [matrix multiplication operator '@'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/). It makes code more clear.

The results is
[transformed rectanlge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rQ76.png)